# One to many relationship data addition for multiple level not working properly in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, relationship

I have a MS Access application with four levels of one to many relationships. The levels are as below:

```
Scenario ->> Attractiveness->> Metrics->> Parameters
```

I have a set of attractiveness, metrics and parameters list all the data are independent. We can map one attractiveness with any number of metrics and for that metrics I need to map parameters. The first higher level is scenario so I am going to create scenarios. So for a scenario we can have only two attractiveness. Then for that two attractiveness user can map any metrics available. In the next level user need to select the parameters for given attractiveness->>Metrics levels.

Please find the below image of my relationship between these tables.

[image: img: Relationship]

I am using the datasheet view to enter data for each level in a sub form. Please find the below data entry sub form

[image: img: Data Entry Sheet in Relationship]

Please find the below relationship keys:

> Scenario Table PK-> (Scenario ID with no Duplicates) -> Attractiveness Table FK ->(Scenario ID with Duplicates)
>
> Attractiveness Table PK ->(Attractiveness ID with no Duplicates) - > Metrics Table FK->(Attractiveness ID with Duplicates)
>
> Metrics Table PK ->(AttractivenessMetrics ID with no Duplicates) - > Parameter Table FK->(AttractivenessMetrics ID with Duplicates)

I can able to add level by level (i.e adding attractiveness, Metrics then update the attID, MetricID, attMetricID in Metric table) then add parameter level is working fine. But if I add parameter without updating the previous metric level then all the parameter are added into the first metric. Since I have no AttractivenessMetrics ID combination in Metrics Table.

Comment: Why are you not saving designated Primary Key as Foreign Key values? Linking should be on PK/FK. I have never set up a database for direct interaction with tables for data entry, always build forms. Don't really understand issue as stated. Parent records must be created before dependent records.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes this is my second question in this forum and I was in a hurry while posting this question. I will correct the changes further and thanks for the updates.

Comment: @June7 Actually if i make the data entry in forms. It would take more time to update the details that users don't link. I am using the tables as temp tables once data updated i will push them into one table.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by using form timer control to keep track of the active control. So while users moving into parameter level updation form metrics level then it will update the metric tables fields this will fix the no parent issues in parameter level. It works well and easy to update the data.